# How to get Home, End, Delete keys working for PuTTY SSH sessions to Cisco ASA?

Tags: ssh, cisco-asa, putty

I want to be able to use Home, End and Delete keys when using PuTTY to access the CLI on my Cisco ASAs.  Currently when I use these keys I see the ~ character.

I have tried changing the PuTTY session Keyboard setting for Home and End from Standard to rxvt - this resulted in Delete giving ~, Home doing nothing at all, and End giving w.

Is it possible to get my keyboard to behave?

I have this all working fine for connections to Linux, but not Cisco devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the ASA CLI your home, end and delete functions are replaced by:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> `home`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> `end`
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> `delete`

Comment: +1 Unfortunately Cisco decided they wanted it broken like this.

Answer (score 1):

Set Terminal > Keyboard > The function keys and keypad to "SCO"

Comment: For Kitty use:  Terminal > Keyboard > `Home and End keys` to `xterm`

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the "Terminal-type string" value to `linux` or `putty` in putty session settings (Connection -> Data -> Terminal-type string).

Comment: Neither option makes any difference when accessing my Cisco devices.  I still get ~ for End, Home, and Delete.